# Checking that nft is selling on opensea

Tags: api, nft, opensea

I want to know some information using Opensea API that some NFT token is selling, but can't find info which api method can give so data. I tried to use events api method which displays all events info of token but can't find the difference between token which is selling and not. For example on the first picture token is selling, on the second one the token isn't
[image]
[image]

Comment: events api. event_type=created.

Answer (score 1):

You can use opensea's api call [retrieve assets](https://docs.opensea.io/reference/getting-assets). This will give you information about an asset and whether or not it is currently listed. As long as you have an api key, it will tell you if the asset is listed, and the details of that order. Hope it helps!